# Create a method that changes attribute (integer) rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes

I have an `integer` in my `Parent` Object's table called `completion_status` with a default value of `0`. Id like to set this to the same value as `"@parent.child.count('completion', :distinct => true)"`, but I have no idea how to do this in the controller, or even if the controller is the best place to do this.

I know there's not much information included here, but let me know if I'm missing something important. I'm having kind of a brain-fart moment here.

**EDIT: Just tried:**

```
def set_completion 
   @app = App.find(params[:id]) 
   @app.update_attribute(:completion_status => @app.elements.count('completion', :distinct => true))
end
```

Comment: Set the value using that line and save it. There are a number of ways to do it, including that, using update_attribute, etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton I just tried out `update_attribute` but I get a `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)` error. Check the edit.

Comment: Well, that's not how update_attribute works. Do you have access to any documentation, either locally (even ri) or on the Web? E.g., http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attribute

Comment: `update_attribute` expects 2 arguments: the name of the attribute and the vale you're updating it to eg: `update_attribute(:quantity, 42)` (which differs from `update_attributes` which takes name/value pairs as a hash)

Comment: @TarynEast I was using a hashrocket instead of a comma for some ungodly reason. Thank you for bringing me back to my senses. Now I only have to factor in the Child's Children's attribute as well and figure out how the hell I'm going to do this.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, this value could possibly change everytime you create a new child, because creating a new child will change the value of `@parent.child.count`, so you want to reset `completion_status` everytime you create or update a new child, so one way to do this is inside the create and update action of the `ChildrenController` -assuming you have one :

```
def create 
  @parent = Parent.find(params[:parent_id]
  @child = @parent.children.build(child_params)
  if @child.save
    @parent.completion_status = @parent.children.count // this is the line to add
  end
end
```

This code could be improved in different ways but I'm just giving you an example.

Comment: @AhmadAk-kheat I'll go ahead and see if I can adapt this for my use and I'll let you know. `completion_status` should only update when a `Child` is edited to change the `boolean` attribute of it from `true` to `false` (hence the `('completion', :distinct => true)`). However, you are indeed right.

Comment: @AhmadAk-kheat Any idea how I'd count the Child's Children with `true`? When I try to I get an `undefined method 'child's child'`

Comment: @Nickdb93 why do you need to count the child's children? I thought a parent has multiple children not a child has multiple children.

Comment: An `App` (parent) has multiple `Elements` (child), each of which has multiple `Features` (child's children). Ultimately, I'd like `completion status` to equal ( `Total Elements` / `Elements Completed` ) + ( `Total Features` / `Features Completed` ). The end goal being to have a generally useful (though not mathematically exact) percentage that can be used in a progress bar.

Comment: @Nickdb93 Ok you can say this : @element.features.where(completed: true).count

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work either :/ However..... I ALSO cannot divide to find the percentage of completed elements of the total elements. `(@app.elements.where(completion: true).count) / (@app.elements.count) )` returns `0.0` for some reason. However, when I just find the ones that are completed, I get the correct number.

Comment: I solved the issue of always returning `0.0` by converting `app.elements.count` to a float. However, I'm still not able to access `features` from within the `apps` controller